# JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a one-to-one relationship but hibernatetool complains when generating the schema. Here's an example that shows the problem:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    public OtherInfo otherInfo;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Person has a one-to-one relationship with OtherInfo:

```
@Entity
public class OtherInfo {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="otherInfo")
    public Person person;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Person is owning side of OtherInfo. OtherInfo is the owned side so person uses `mappedBy` to specify the attribute name "otherInfo" in Person.

I get the following error when using hibernatetool to generate the database schema:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Person, at table: OtherInfo, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(person)]
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.iterateGenerators(Configuration.java:743)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateDropSchemaScript(Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.<init>(SchemaExport.java:128)
        ...
```

Any idea why? Am I a doing something wrong or is this a Hibernate bug?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

JPA doesn't allow the *@Id* annotation on a *OneToOne* or *ManyToOne* mapping. What you are trying to do is one-to-one entity association **with shared primary key**. The simplest case is unidirectional one-to-one with shared key:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private OtherInfo otherInfo;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

The main problem with this is that JPA provides no support for shared primary key generation in *OtherInfo* entity. The classic book [Java Persistence with Hibernate by Bauer and King](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885) gives the following solution to the problem using Hibernate extension:

```
@Entity
public class OtherInfo {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "customForeignGenerator")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(
        name = "customForeignGenerator",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "person")
    )
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="otherInfo")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Person person;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Also, see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_Relationships).

Comment: Great answer, just wanted to add that you may need to add the following annotation as well in your Person class (I had to to get things working correctly): `@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })`

Comment: Thanks, it helped on my problem.. Do you know of anyway use only JPA annotations and avoid the hibernate one?

Comment: @Elton - if there is a way it must be in JPA 2.0 - I didn't look into this though.

Comment: It did work for me, but I had to add `optional=false` to the `@OneToOne` annotation. Otherwise I'd get an exception complaining that person was null.

Answer (score 23):

This should be working too using JPA 2.0 @MapsId annotation instead of Hibernate's GenericGenerator:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public OtherInfo otherInfo;

    rest of attributes ...
}

@Entity
public class OtherInfo {

    @Id
    public int id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    public Person person;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

More details on this in Hibernate 4.1 documentation under section 5.1.2.2.7.

Comment: [Link for the lazy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2666). I chose to use the Id annotation on the OneToOne class itself (OtherInfo in your example), but that only works in a child-parent scenario. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Why did you specify `@JoinColumn` on `OtherInfo` rather than use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`?

Answer (score 10):

You just need to add `@JoinColumn(name="column_name")` to Host Entity relation . column_name is the database column name in person table.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="other_info")
    public OtherInfo otherInfo;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Person has a one-to-one relationship with OtherInfo:
mappedBy="var_name" var_name is variable name for otherInfo in Person class.

```
@Entity
public class OtherInfo {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="otherInfo")
    public Person person;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you still need the primary key property in the OtherInfo class.

```
@Entity
public class OtherInfo {
    @Id
    public int id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="otherInfo")
    public Person person;

    rest of attributes ...
}
```

Also, you may need to add the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation to the other side of the mapping. I know that Hibernate uses this by default. But then I haven't used JPA annotations, which seem to require you to specify how the association wokrs.

Answer (score 2):

I have a better way of doing this:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @OneToOne(cascade={javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "`Id_OtherInfo`")
    public OtherInfo getOtherInfo() {
      return otherInfo;
    }

}
```

That's all

Comment: Also the owned side, i.e. the side that has the foreign key must implement serialisable (with hiberate 4 /jpa 2)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can use a relationship as an Id/PrimaryKey in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Entity

@Table(name="tblperson")

public class Person {

public int id;

public OtherInfo otherInfo;
@Id //Here Id is autogenerated
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity=OtherInfo.class)
@JoinColumn(name="otherInfo_id") //there should be a column otherInfo_id in Person
public OtherInfo getOtherInfo() {
    return otherInfo;
}
public void setOtherInfo(OtherInfo otherInfo) {
    this.otherInfo= otherInfo;
}
rest of attributes ...
}


@Entity

@Table(name="tblotherInfo")

public class OtherInfo {

private int id;

private Person person;

@Id

@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

  @OneToOne(mappedBy="OtherInfo",targetEntity=Person.class)   
public College getPerson() {
    return person;
}
public void setPerson(Person person) {
    this.person = person;
}    
 rest of attributes ...
}
```