# Hibernate zeroToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, shared-primary-key

I am trying to establish a relationship between 2 entities which would be zero-to-one. That is, the Parent can be saved without the associated Child entity and also along with the assoicated Child.
Following are the 2 Entity classes...

---

**Employee (Parent)**

```
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="EMP_NAME")
    private String name;

    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private EmployeeInfo info;

    @Column(name="EMP_ENUM")
    private Integer enumId;
```

---

**EmployeeInfo (Child)**

```
public class EmployeeInfo {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_EMAIL")
        private String email;
```

With such kind of a relation and id column of the only **Parent (Employee) table set to AUTO INCREMENT in MySql DB**, the problem is that while saving a Parent->Child object graph, I get the following exception

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into EMP_INFO 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value
```

I tried setting the **Child Table's Id property to AUTO INCREMENT in the DB** , and the persistence of such a Parent->Child object graph is successful. 
However, the problem described [here](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2128) surfaces, because I have a scenario in which I would like to save the parent (Employee) object without the associated EmpInfo object, and **hence do NOT want to have AUTO INCREMENT on the Child's id column**.

---

One solution could be not use the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn, but use a particular JoinColumn, but that adds an unnecessary column to my existing Table.

---

Has anyone come across such a problem? If yes, any pointers would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a scenario in which I would like to save the parent (Employee) object without the associated EmpInfo object.

The `optional` attribute of a `OneToOne` is `true` by default, which is what you want.

However, you are somehow misusing the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` here (well, it actually depends on what you really want to achieve but your current combination of annotations is not correct).

**IF** you want to map a `OneToOne` **with a shared primary-key**, use the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`. But in that case, don't use a `GeneratedValue` on `EmployeeInfo` and set the id manually or, if you don't want to set it manually, use the Hibernate **specific** `foreign` generator that I already mentioned in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492608/hibernate-jpa-one-to-one-saving-child-class-entity). Check also the related question mentioned below.

And **IF** you do not want to use a shared primary key (like in your current code since you're trying to get the id generated by the database), then **do not use** the `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

You have to make a choice.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 specification:

  - 9.1.32 `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` Annotation

#### Related question

- [JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship).

Comment: Hey Pascal, Thanks for your response as always :) 
As for your suggestion "don't use a GeneratedValue on EmployeeInfo and set it manually" - The problem would be that before saving the parent (Employee) I would not have the id associated with it, and hence I cannot it manually to the child object. As for "use the Hibernate specific foreign generator", I have tried that already but it gives me an NPE (I will paste the stack trace and what I did when I lay my hands on the code again, tomorrow).
Btw, what makes you think that I do not want to use a shared primary key? Infact,I want that!

Comment: Continuing my previous comment.. I want to use shared primary key, what in my code makes you feel that I do not want it? However, with the shared primary key join column, I also want 2 scenarios to be satisfied i) The parent saved alone ii) Parent along with the child saved - in which case the shared primary key would come into picture actually. I hope that makes the question more clear.

Comment: Also, yes thanks for pointing me my previous post. It was the earlier approach that I was planning (that is to save the child entity separately by setting into it manually, the parent's id). I have now changed the approach, to make it less bug prone, by saving the entire object graph ( from parent -> child, even in the case when I want the child alone to be saved).

Comment: @PaiS: `Btw, what makes you think that I do not want to use a shared primary key?` Because we saw yesterday that this can't work with `@GeneratedValue` without using the specific `foreign` generator, which is what you are trying to do in this question :)

Comment: @PaiS: `However, with the shared primary key join column, I also want 2 scenarios to be satisfied i) The parent saved alone ii) Parent along with the child saved` I don't see the problem, having a `null` child should be possible. Feel free to update the question with accurate mappings and stack trace.

Comment: @Pascal: " Then you can't use a shared primary-key (if there is no parent, there is no FK)" --> Just to reframe, (as already mentioned too), I want 2 scenarios to be satisfied 1) The parent saved alone 2) The parent along with the child saved (in which case the primary key Join column would come into picture ofcourse). I do want the child alone to be saved in any case/scenario.

Comment: @Pascal - thanks for the suggestion about updating the question. I have highlighted a few things and added a line to indicate what I really want to achieve. Also, as an answer to your previous comment, the parent save with the null child is successful always and never carries a problem. The only time the problem occurs is when the scenario mentioned in the URL (of my original post) occurs.

Comment: @PaiS: Note that I removed my comment about saving a child without the parent :) That was an incorrect interpretation.

Comment: @PaiS: And sorry for insisting but I'm saying the same thing as in Christian's comment to [HHH-2128](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2128?focusedCommentId=24695&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_24695) which has been rejected: `You obviously can't use a shared primary key one-to-one mapping with automatically assigned native primary keys.`

Comment: @Pascal: Yep, thanks for that. I have changed the implementation to be bidirectional now, giving the @GenericGenerator on the child entity. I will "answer" the question and provide the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got it working thanks to Pascal and some googling from my side. Apparently, I cannot use the Native key generator for such relationships where the parent can exist without the child (optional = true).
The thing that worked finally was the following, leaving me the downside of having to deal with Hibernate specific annotation (@GenericGenerator) and also having to make-do with bi-directional relationships instead of the unidirectional that I wanted.

```
Employee (Parent) class remains unchanged as above. It has AUTO INCREMENT on the Id column.
```

As for the child class (EmployeeInfo) it changed to the following, and again **WITHOUT** having the AUTO INCREMENT set on the Id column.

```
@Table(name="EMP_INFO")
@Entity
public class EmployeeInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="foreign")
    @GenericGenerator(name="foreign", strategy = "foreign", parameters={
    @Parameter(name="property", value="verifInfo")}) 
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn (name="id")
    private Employee emp;

    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_EMAIL")
    private String email;
```

This helped me achieve what I wanted but on the downside, GenericGenerator is not a JPA annotation, it is a hibernate annotation, and sadly I have to make do with that as of now because JPA does not currently support this(or any similar) annotation.

Anyway, it helps to get through such cases :-)