# @OnetoOne VS @SecondaryTable annotation in Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a situation like , I need to save some receipt details in a table and along with that receipt file will also be there. SO I decided to keep 2 table one for receipt_details and other for `receipt_file`

```
class ReceiptDetails{

@Id
int id;

BigDecimal amount;

//Otherstuff
}
```

Here i have to include `receiptFile` details such as content, filename etc from second table as well.

Should I use `@OnetoOne` or `@SecondaryTable` in this scenario. In what situation each annotation fits?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512721/secondarytables-or-onetoone-associations

Comment: @Hannes It only says if you want seperate entity for second table then only use OnetoOne. I will use fetch eager in one to one and not required it as a seperate entity. But is that justification enough to use secondary table? or any other hidden features?

Comment: If you're targeting the combination for `value=TYPE`, then you'd go for `@SecondaryTable`. if its just for target `value=METHOD,FIELD` go for `@OneToOne`.

Comment: @procrastinator I didnt understand that targeting the combination? If you don't mind, could you please brief little bit.