# Mock JOINED inheritance strategy without actual inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I want to use mixed @Inheritance strategy, but Hibernate doesn't support it.
Is there any way to implement **JOINED** inheritance without actual class inheritance.
For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A { 
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ID_SEQ")
  private Long id;

  //getters
  //setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class B {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  //getters
  //setters
}
```

So, basically in `B` I just want to refer to @Id generated in `A` without extending from `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. JPA doesn't allow you to combine `@Id` and `@OneToOne`. However, `@MapsId` annotation does the trick:

```
@Entity
public class A { 
  @Id
  private Long id;

  //getters
  //setters
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @MapsId
  @OneToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="id")
  private A a;

  //getters
  //setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by making a @OneToOne relationship or a @OneToMany and point the table name like this

```
  @Id @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id")
  private A a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship) the Id annotation cannot be combined with OneToOne.

Comment: I found the solution. Check it out, if you're interested.