# Entity as key on a One to One relationship returning "Composite-ID" error

Tags: java, spring, one-to-one, composite-key, hibernate-annotations

I have the following 2 entities:

```
   @Entity(name = "Employee")
   @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
   public class Employee implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "EMP_ID", insertable = true, updatable = false, nullable = false)
      private int id;
```

and

```
@Entity(name = "Draw")
@Table(name = "DRAW")

public class Draw extends AuditableEntity {
    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMP_ID")
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
        org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Employee employee = null;
```

Let's just say that's the way they want it modeled. This is a OneToOne relationship as specified. However, when I go to test I get the following error:

> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/datasource-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.myprojects.tet.data.entity.Draw

Why is the `employee` key in `Draw` interpreted as a composite-id? Also how do I fix this error. [I have read](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2306165&sid=857145b56a9e06c8fa10aca8199c7312) that the entity referenced has to be serializable but also that it needs to implement method `equals` and `hashCode` (which I haven't implemented yet). Should implementation of those two fix that error?

**Editing for clarity:**

I have two modeled tables: `EMPLOYEE` and `DRAW`:

`EMPLOYEE` has: integer `emp_id`, plus a lot of other columns.

`DRAW` has: integer `emp_id`, integer `totalPoints`.

The draw table will be populated and purged every certain time, so column `totalPoint` cannot be in table `EMPLOYEE`. I am unsure if my entity relations are correct (i.e. having entity `employee` as the id for `draw`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `@JoinColumn` with [`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html):

```
@Id
@Column(name = "EMP_ID")
private int id;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "EMP_ID")
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE})
private Employee employee;
```

Comment: @Nimchip: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698), looks like a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Tomasz it looks like it is the same thing. If I'm understanding correctly both are different approaches (the JPA one and the book one), is this assumption correct?

Comment: @Nimchip: if you refer to an answer mentioned by me above, they provide a solution using Hibernate-specific annotation.