# Missing column: id on a one-to-one mapping with shared PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, shared-primary-key

I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but I can't make it work. I have a one-to-zero-or-one relationship with shared primary key between an entity `Home` and an entity `Address`.

My problem is that I keep getting an error

> Missing column: id

I'm mapping my entities as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12140548/3748908), but a difference, the column name for my `Address` entity is not called `id` but `homeId_pf`.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "homes")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Home implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;


    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "homeId_fk", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = {ALL})
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address address;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "homeId_pf")
    private Long id;

    private Integer city;


    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Home home;
}
```

As said, my `addresses` table has two columns: `homeId_pf`, that is set as PK and a FK to `homes.id` and `city`.

I've also tried setting `@JoinColumn(name = "homeId_pf")` on the `Address` class, and `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "homeId_pf")` on the `Home` entity, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Probably a duplicate question: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938253/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of problems with one-to-one associations, see

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2158
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1849

The problem is generally that a query Home.address.id = ? is replaced by Home.id = ? as if it was a shared primary key one-to-one (instead of your one-to-zero-or-one).

Hibernate does the same error when working on a foreign key one-to-one.

Are you doing Criteria or HQL query ?
In Criteria, you can avoid the issue creating an alias on Home.address and querying alias.id. In HQL, you can make a subquery.

I did not have time to correct the bug in Hibernate, but if you have a test case, I think the problem comes from that code in org.hibernate.engine.JoinHelper.getAliasedLHSColumnNames() :

```
if ( type.useLHSPrimaryKey() ) {
        return StringHelper.qualify( alias, lhsPersister.getIdentifierColumnNames() );
    }
```

I think it should also check that type.getLHSPropertyName() is not filled by a "property-ref" attribute in a XML mapping.
If you have a test case, it would be good to submit the issue to Hibernate and suggest that fix.