# Hibernate @OneToOne mappedBy

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, mappedby

I'm facing the following problem:
I have one table A and B with a foreign key to table A.
An entity has the following field:
A:

```
public class A{

    @Column(name = "id_adres", nullable = false)
    private Long idAddress;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_adres", nullable = false)
    private Long idAddress;
```

B entity has a field (among others):

```
public class B{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_adres", nullable = false)
    private Long idAddress;
    @Column(name = "id_adres", nullable = false)
    private Long idAddress;
```

How to add the field of type B to A entity?
A:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "idAddress")
private B b
```

This solution doesn't work, field B b in A entity is NULL after the query statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Hibernate One-to-One relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work with OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn - maybe because I have Long instead of a object type in B entity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the long is not the reason I have the same example with long try like this:

```
public class UserToken {
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
    private long tokenId;

}

public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long userId;

}
```

Comment: And your entity (table) UserToken doesn't have foreign key to the User?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to put the foreign key for the user. There are many ways you can use one of for oneToOne like https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column

Comment: Doesn't work - maybe the problem is that I use query: address = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Address b WHERE...

Comment: Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Address a WHERE a.filedName= :filedName");
      query.setParameter("filedName", value);      and  query.getResultList();

Comment: and JOIN? There is not foreign key on table Address (A) to the B property so maybe should I use JOIN? SELECT a FROM Address a JOIN a.addressProperty ap ON ap.idAddress = a.idAddress WHERE a.idClient=:id")

Comment: em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM Address b left JOIN b.addressProperty ap WHERE b.idClient=:id").setParameter("id", idClient).getResultList(); WORKS! Thank you @ikarayel!

Comment: I found the following BUG - probably its my case! https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7307